# include object inside a class or better derive from that class?

Tags: c++

I'm quite new in C++ and I would like to learn good practices from the beginning, so my question explained with an example is:

Having:

```
class A
{
    int mNumber;
};
```

If I need to use class A inside class B, what is better?to include an object?

```
class B
{
    A * mpA;
    int mColor;
};
```

Or inherit from Class A?

```
class B : public A
{
    int mColor;
};
```

Is there any good habit talking in a generally way to do this?

Comment: Ops! sorry, I was looking for it and I couldn't find an answer...thanks! :)

Comment: The duplicate linked by John certainly explains the composition/inheritance aspect very well. Prefer composition in this case. But I would add to the C++ aspect: don't do `A *mpA`, do `A mA`. The default in C++ is to handle objects as values (which they are) and only resort to dynamic allocation if it's necessary.

Comment: @Angew `A*` doesn't imply dynamic allocation. If `B` doesn't own `mpA`, it doesn't make sense to have an object as a member, and a pointer (smart or not) is the way to go.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Of course. But given that the OP describes themselves as "quite new" and is considering inheritance, I consider it safe to assume `B` will actually own an `A` and the pointer was going to be an owning one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefer composition over inheritance - however remember that for each particular situation, the other approach might be better.

Composition is:

```
class A
{
    B b;
};
```

Inheritence is:

```
class A : public B
{
};
```

Use the first when the relationship is "has-a" and the latter when it is "is-a".

Your example is a loose type of composition - if the member is a pointer, it doesn't (necessarily) signify ownership.

Comment: Thanks for the good and brief explanation! :)

Comment: BTW, how did you get an answer through the closure?

Comment: @Angew I believe there was a thread on meta a while back about closed questions not being "server-side closed" for a couple of minutes, and you can easily get past the client-side restriction. Given I was already 9/10 through with my answer when the question got closed, I didn't want to discard it.

Comment: Fair enough. The answer's correct of course, have an upvote :-)